# Amount of memory transfer on a running Linux

Tags: linux, performance, memory, ram

Can I determinate the amount of RAM exchange (between the CPU and the RAM) on a running Linux system?

I'm not looking for the max RAM speed (then memtest would be valid answer). I'm looking for the amount of megabytes of RAM that is read/written by the processor (without swapping).

Is there a utility or a /{proc,sys} entry on Linux for this?

Comment: Memory-to-CPU transfer is managed by the hardware and most real hardware has no built-in memory statistics unit. OTOH simulated hardware (virtual machines) and profilers can often report such statistics.